# Does your Amazon Redshift database need be in the same region as your Machine Learning model?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-machine-learning

When trying to use Amazon Redshift to create a datasource for my Machine Learning model, I encountered the following error when testing the access of my IAM role:

> There is no '' cluster, or the cluster is not in the same region as your Amazon ML service. Specify a cluster in the same region as the Amazon ML service.

Is there anyway around this, as this would be a huge pain since all of our development team's data is stored in a region that Machine Learning doesn't work in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an interesting situation to be in. 
What probably you can do :

1) Wait for Amazon Web Services to support AWS ML in your preferred Region. (That's a long wait though).

2) OR what else you can do is **Create a backup plan** for your Redshift data.

> Amazon Redshift provides you some by Default tools to back up your
>   cluster via snapshot to Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3).
>   These snapshots can be restored in any AZ in that region or
>   transferred automatically to other regions wherever you want (In your
>   case where your ML is running).

*There is (Probably) no other way around to use your ML with Redshift being in different regions.*

Hope it will help !